# Facebook use API without extending Activity from FacebookActivity on Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I have an Activity which already extends from my own custom Activtiy class.

How can I work with Facebook API like without extending FacebookActivtiy.

I call LoginActivity and get access_token, but what I have to do after that?

Please give link if you know?

I try to use old scheme i.e to create new instance of class Facebook with app_id, but SDK tells that Facebook class is depreceated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should get the latest version of the API (if you haven't already), which is the v3.0 that you can find [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/).

A detailed description of how to implement the authentication logic without extending  Facebook's `LoginActivity` is found [here.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/#advanced1)

Hope it helps!